# Opencv C++ create a Mat of Mats

Tags: c++, opencv, vector, mat

I am trying to build a distance matrix between frames in C++ with OpenCv 2.4.10. I think I need a mat of mats so I can put in the first row and col all the frames and make a XOR operator frame by frame. But to do so I need a structure like a matrix that contains in each position another matrix. Is there a thing like a Mat of Mats? Or can you suggest another solution? I thought of useing Vector but I need more than an array of Mat. Thank you I am new at this!

Answer (score 1):

If I got it correctly, what you are looking for is a 2-dimensional Mat object, whose each element is another 2-dimensional Mat object. This is equivalent to creating a 4-dimensional Mat object. OpenCV has such a functionality - it just involves using one of less popular and less convenient Mat constructors:

```
const int num_of_dim = 4;
const int dimensions[num_of_dim] = { a, b, c, d }; // a, b, c, d - desired dimensions defined elsewhere
cv::Mat fourd_mat(num_of_dim, dimensions, CV_32F);
```

Check **Mat::Mat(int ndims, const int* sizes, int type)**  constructor at openCV docs:

http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.10/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#Mat::Mat(int%20ndims,%20const%20int*%20sizes,%20int%20type)

as well as search for the phrase "multi-dimensional" and "n-dimensional" on that page to find more examples and docs.

**EDIT:**

As requested, I'm showing how to load an image into such a structure. It's not pretty, but I guess the easiest way is to copy the image pixel by pixel:

```
img = imread("path/img.jpg", 1);
for (int i = 0; i < 179; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; i < img.rows; ++i)
    {
        for (int k = 0; j < img.cols; ++j)
        {
            const int coords1[4] = { i, 0, j, k };
            const int coords2[4] = { 0, i, j, k };
            fourd_mat.at<float>(coords1) = img.at<float>(j, k); //line 1
            fourd_mat.at<float>(coords2) = img.at<float>(j, k); //line 2
        }
    }
}
```

The line commented as **line1** is equivalent to your line **struttura[i][0] = img;** and **line2** is equivalent to **struttura[0][i] = img;** after the two innermost for loops finish their work.

The code above assumes that your image type is **CV_32F** - if it's **8UC**, you have to replace **float** with **uchar** in **at()** function.

Comment: Hey, is this what you were looking for?